# What is the correct way to run GWT JUnit test when using GWT `tbroyer` maven plugin?

Tags: java, gwt

What is the proper approach to run a JUnit test for a GWT project that uses [tbroyer maven plugin](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-plugin)

I have created a sample application to showcase a failing test that throws

```
Loading inherited module 'com.todogwt.App'
   [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/todogwt/App.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
```

Here is the code: https://github.com/incube8r/todogwt

The test is just as very simple

```
public class TestHelloWorld extends GWTTestCase {

    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return "com.todogwt.App";
    }

    public void test() {
        Window.alert("Hello world!");
        Console.log("Hello world!");
        delayTestFinish(1000);
        finishTest();
    }

}
```

With the test `module.gwt.xml` located under

`src/test/module.gwt.xml`

What is the correct way to run JUnit test when using GWT `tbroyer` maven plugin?

Answer (score 5):

`gwt:test` by default wants you to use test suites: https://tbroyer.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes; you can run with `-Dtest=TestHelloWorld` but you'll have to update to the latest version of the gwt-maven-plugin (1.0-rc-10 for now); or you could redefine the `<includes>` to match your test.

Last, but not least, `src/test/module.gwt.xml` is not used by anything; only `src/main/module.gwt.xml` is. You don't have any difference between those files though, and your problem is actually that your test class is not in the source path for the module: move it to the `client` subpackage to make it run (and pass).

Comment: Any chance this can be made to work with java 11 and up? I'm getting the following error for the said repo of the OP:
```java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.GC```

Comment: AFAICS the test actually passes, the error message is only a log as it appears. Tested with 2.8.2 and 2.9.0-RC1. Is this something to worry about?